How to Open an Newly Created Record from flow in a subtab
I am invoking the flow on quickaction button.I am inserting an record through the flow and navigating to record detail page by using lwc.Currently the newly created record is opening in new tab.How can i open it in subtab instead of opening it in new tab.I tried following ways but navigation is not happening and not opening in subtab.
First way that i tried:
connectedCallback(){
    this.isLoading=true;
        openTab({
             url: '/lightning/r/Asset/this.recordIdToRedirect/view',
             label: 'Global Media',
             focus: true
        }).catch((error) => {
             console.log(error);
        });
    
    this.isLoading=false;
}

Second way:
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('subtab', {
    detail: {
      recordId
    }
  }));

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

It should be as simple as: openTab({ recordId: this.recordIdToRedirect }), but we don't have enough context here. Please include enough code so that we can fully appreciate the context.

Then do i need to add like this?        connectedCallback(){
openTab({ recordId: this.recordIdToRedirect })
} but this did not worked  @sfdcfox
